# SDK Installing problem

Tags: android, sdk, java

I have installed JDK. but while installing SDK it is showing there is no JDK in your system.Any one has any idea what can i do ?

Comment: When you get the error, try clicking back once, then next immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that you're on a 64-bit Windows machine and you installed the 64-bit Java JDK. You need to also install the 32-bit JRE.